A7682E LTE modem parse file downloading with UART
I need to parse the data that SIMCOM A7682E modem is sending to the UART.
It seems simple until I tried to do that. The main problem is that modem does not waiting between data packets. So there is no delay before \r\n+CFTPSGET: DATA,1024\r\n event to parse previous data packet. Instead it starts sending new packet of data right after previous is sent. I prepared a screenshot to illustrate that

Honestly I have no idea how to parse it correctly. I tried to search for that string with
strstr((char*)atc->rxBuffer, "\r\n+CFTPSGET: ");

But seems that my algorithm makes MCU to miss characters. I`m using STM32F103CBT6 at 72 MHz.
In the following code the data_size variable increases only one time on the first occurrence of the +CFTPSGET: line.
void atc_rxCallback(atc_t *atc)
{
  if (LL_USART_IsActiveFlag_RXNE(atc->usart))
  {
    uint8_t tmp = LL_USART_ReceiveData8(atc->usart);
    if (atc->rxIndex < _ATC_RXSIZE - 1)
    {
      atc->rxBuffer[atc->rxIndex] = tmp;
      atc->rxIndex++;

      if (fota_started) {                           /* Algo for FOTA only */
        if (atc->rxIndex >= strlen("\r\n+CFTPSGET: ")) {        /* Checking that received more characters than start packet has */
            char* str = strstr((char*)atc->rxBuffer, "\r\n+CFTPSGET: ");
            if (str != NULL) {      /* Looking for a FTP related string in the buffer */
                uint16_t packet_size = 1;

                data_size += packet_size;
                memset(atc->rxBuffer, 0, _ATC_RXSIZE);
                atc->rxIndex = 0;
            }
        }
      }

    }
    atc->rxTime = HAL_GetTick();

    return;
  }
}


Okay, I got some information and did the part of my feature.
As I'm trying to receive a firmware binary file for future update the file contains a 0x00 or '\0' bytes in it.
When I`m receiving them into the array and using strstr function it interprets them as null-termination characters. Meanwhile as it should be for that function and IDK why I didn't remember that.
I found similar question on stackoverflow here and tried that memmem function that guy provided. And it works damn good.
Of course I need to correctly process data and so on. But at least I can use event-strings as delimiters to parse a file.
